# Ruby Nested Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a nested array that looks like this:

```
@nested = [
  ['1','2','3'],
  ['1','5','9'],
  ['1','4','7'],
  ['3','5','7'],
  ['3','6','9'],
  ['7','8','9'],
  ['4','5','6'],
  ['2','5','8']
]
```

I'd like to take a user input of any integer (that 1..9) and find every array that has that input integer.

Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
num_to_search = "9"
@nested.select do |array|
  array.include? num_to_search
end
#=> [["1", "5", "9"], ["3", "6", "9"], ["7", "8", "9"]]
```

Comment: I had to put `if array.include?(num_to_search) puts array.inspect end` to get your output. The original just gave me a sequence of `true/false`. I am stuck with Ruby 1.8.7 at the moment. Is that the cause?

Comment: @ScottJShea It shouldn't print anything, it should return that array of arrays. I've just verified that the return value is what I show in my answer in both Ruby 1.8.7 & 1.9.3.